# Copy sheet without creating new instances of named ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to copy a sheet.  I also have a few named ranges that are scoped to the Workbook.  The problem is, when I do the copy, it creates duplicates of all the named ranges with a scope of the new sheet.  Everything works of course but I could potentially have 20+ sheets.  I don't need 80 named ranges that are mostly duplicates.  How can I avoid this?

```
Sub btnCopyTemplate()
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set template = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
    newSheet.Name = "NewCopy"
End Sub
```

And the Name Manager after a copy:

[image]

Comment: Quick suggestion: Instead of copying the entire `Sheet`, what if instead you just copies all the `Cells`? That way, you would just keep the data, no named ranges. ie: `Sheets("mainSheet").Cells.Copy Sheets("newSheet").Cells`.

Comment: You can delete the names after creating the sheet.  I don't think there's a setting which controls whether they get created with the copy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
Sub btnCopyTemplate()
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set template = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
    newSheet.Name = "NewCopy"
    deleteNames 'Check the sub
End Sub

Sub deleteNames()
    Dim theName As Name
    For Each theName In Names
        If TypeOf theName.Parent Is Worksheet Then
            theName.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This way you will delete all the names with the scope "worksheet" and keep the "workbook" names

**Edit#2**

After read the comments here is the update passing the sheet to loop only the "newSheet"

```
Sub btnCopyTemplate()
    Dim template As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set template = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    template.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
    newSheet.Name = "NewCopy"
    deleteNames newSheet
End Sub

Sub deleteNames(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim theName As Name
    For Each theName In Names
        If (TypeOf theName.Parent Is Worksheet) And (sht.Name = theName.Parent.Name) Then
            theName.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a moot point with so little names, but if there lots of names, you could specify which worksheet to loop through and only delete the names in the worksheet. As well as pass a worksheet argument into the Sub so it works with specific sheets.

Comment: I would very much like to see a version that passes the "NewCopy" sheet to the `deleteNames` sub so that it only deletes named ranges which fall into the scope of the newly created worksheet.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate - how do we know the scope and if the ranges fit in the new sheet? So you *do* want to keep *some* named ranges?

Comment: @BruceWayne: I don't, but it's possible I might have a sheet that does have named ranges scoped only to that sheet.  If the copy procedure passed the newly created sheet to the delete procedure then it deleted only the names in that scope, it still accomplishes the goal but reduces the risk of deleting something unintentionally, right?

Comment: I just finished modifying it on my own.  It worked but yours is slightly different (probably more robust).  Thanks!